How to create a model with null values ​in Prisma ORM?
I’m using Prisma ORM with MongoDB, and when creating a new document, I need the completedAt field to be included, even if it doesn't have a value yet. In the future, this field will be updated, but at the time of creation, I would like MongoDB to set it explicitly as null by default.
Here is the model I’m using:
model Example{
    id           String   @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
    updatedAt    DateTime @updatedAt
    createdAt    DateTime   @default(now())
    completedAt DateTime?
}

How can I configure this so that during document creation, the completedAt field is explicitly set to null when using Prisma ORM with MongoDB?
I expect:
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "123"
  },
  "updatedAt": {
    "$date": "2024-10-17T21:37:13.778Z"
  },
  "completedAt": null,
  "createdAt": {
      "$date": "2024-10-17T21:37:13.778Z"
    }
  }
}

